# PowerShell/WPF: Disable Button on Click

Tags: wpf, powershell

I'm writing a little toolbox at work for the common vSphere tasks. This time around, I wanted to dip into WPF.
I have created an initial connect-to-server GUI, and everything works as designed. But now I'm stuck at the following:

When clicking the `Connect` button (`btnConnect`), I want it to become greyed out/disabled, followed by the connection attempt. Once the attempt is done, it can become active again. This is to prevent people from clicking on it multiple times in a row.

This is my first attempt *(I'm unable to show the complete thing, given that it's 4 files and there's some stuff in it that I'm not allowed to freely share, so I will post what's relevant)*:

```
$Window.btnConnect.Add_Click({
  $Window.btnConnect.IsEnabled = $False
  $Window.btnConnect.Content = 'Connecting...'
  Connect-CompanyVIServer -VIServer 'ServerName' -VICredential 'PSCredentialObject'
  $Window.btnConnect.Content = 'Connect'
  $Window.btnConnect.IsEnabled = $True
})
```

Essentially, I **disable** the button, change it's text to `Connecting...`, and connect to the VMware vCenter Server. Afterwards I change the button label back and re-enable it.

When I click on the button, the form hangs while it's loading and making the connection attempt. This is to be expected, being that they're in the same thread. That's fine, since the form should do anything until the attempt is completed anyway *(and learning both WPF AND runspaces at the same time would make it too complex)*.

The problem is that even though the `$Window.btnConnect.IsEnabled = $False` is at the top, the form doesn't actually update until the entire block is done processing. Until that time, I can continue clicking on the button and it'll just buffer the attempts and execute them after one-another.

So I figured I'd split them up into separate events:

```
$Window.btnConnect.Add_Click({ $Window.btnConnect.IsEnabled = $False })

$Window.btnConnect.Add_IsEnabledChanged({
  If ($Window.btnConnect.IsEnabled -eq $False) {
    $Window.btnConnect.Content = 'Connecting...'
    Connect-CompanyVIServer -VIServer 'ServerName' -VICredential 'PSCredentialObject'
    $Window.btnConnect.Content = 'Connect'
    $Window.btnConnect.IsEnabled = $True
  }
})
```

A valiant attempt, didn't work though. I get the exact same thing.

So now I'm out of ideas. I was considering writing a trigger into the WPF code to disable the button, but I have no idea if that works. If I do something to run the connection attempt asynchronously, I'd need to be able to query fir the outcome somehow. I'm still experimenting. In the meantime, I come here for help.

My goal is to open a new window once the connection is present and then let it close this window. The important part is that I prevent users from clicking on the button more than once.

Anyone?

Comment: The UI can be updated while your connection is in progress. You need to connect on a background thread and update the on the UI thread.

Comment: So no matter what I do, I'm forced to use runspaces? Am I going to need a time-ticker (I don't even know what that is, but someone mentioned it)? I've been digging into runspaces, but it'll require me to rewrite half the module.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment above alludes to, turning the button off, doing work, and then turning it on again is on a particular thread, but not the thread that updates the GUI.  It seems as though it happens instantaneously from the GUI thread perspective, i.e. off then on, nothing happens.

If you use the dispatcher to send a message to the GUI thread, i.e.

```
   $Window.Dispatcher.invoke([action]{$Window.btnConnect.IsEnabled -eq $False})
```

you would see that now you have successfully disabled the button (grayed it out) after a single click. Unfortunately, that's now a permanent situation on the GUI.

To do the "turn off, work, turn on" in a different thread, using a runspace, would go something like (forgive me if not perfect):

```
function my_func {
   param($Window,$btnConnect)

   $Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
   $Runspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
   $Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
   $Runspace.Open()
   $Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("Window",$Window)
   $Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("btnConnect",$btnConnect)


    #add server name/credentials with SetVariable so they can be seen in code block
    $code = {
        $Window.Dispatcher.invoke(
        [action] {$Window.Dispatcher.btnConnect.IsEnabled = $False})
        $Window.btnConnect.Content = 'Connecting...'
        Connect-CompanyVIServer -VIServer 'ServerName' -VICredential 'PSCredentialObject'
        $Window.btnConnect.Content = 'Connect'
        #below line throws away any clicks since we've disabled button
        [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
        $Window.Dispatcher.invoke(
        [action] {$Window.Dispatcher.btnConnect.IsEnabled = $True})
    }

    $PSinstance = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($code)
    $PSinstance.Runspace = $Runspace
    $job = $PSinstance.BeginInvoke()
}

$Window.btnConnect.Add_Click({
  my_func $Window $Window.btnConnect
})
```